# AuthorizationHandler and database dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0, asp.net-identity-3

We develop an multi-tenant application based on Identity authentication. Each user get a token session, stored in database, to tell if the user is still connected (with expiration time). I store the token (and others informations about the user company) in user `Claim`. After that Identity detect that the user is still connected (or not), I need to check if the user token is still valid in our database  (but only if he's connected), so I implemented `AuthorizationHandler`.

```
public TokenValidHandler(MyDatabaseService service)
{
     // No information about the user connection string
}

protected override async void Handle(AuthorizationContext context, TokenValidRequirement requirement)
{
    // Check the token in database
}
```

And I register my Handler like this :

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
     options.AddPolicy("TokenValid",policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new TokenValidRequirement()));
});

 services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, TokenValidHandler>();
```

Because we have an multi-tenant application, when the user quit the application and re-open the site, his connection string is lost (and we don't want to persist database string), so I use informations stored in `Claim` to recover the database access. If the authentication expired, no informations are available in `Claim`, so I cannot access to my database.

As I can see, `TokenValidHandler` is instanciated even if the user is not connected, is that normal ? Because in the case he's not, and I wanted to use dependency injection for my database service, I cannot because informations about the user database access are not here : Identity is not detecting soon enough that the user authentication expired. Any ideas about that ?

Comment: I found the solution to use  IServiceProvider  for the moment, so I get my database service into the  Handler  method and not via dependency injection, not so clean solution ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try registering your handler as scoped, and you will get a new instance per request which is probably what you want.

Comment: It's true, but what if I've got 5000 handlers registered as scoped, why all of them instantiated any time when I interact any actions? They could have dependencies on other services which should be injected.